# how to sync mac local directory with native docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

i am using native docker for mac and i have a small application running with docker container .

currently i am manually copying the data from my mac to docker container using `docker cp`  command.

i want to make it dynamic, i want to put the data in my local directory which should get sync with docker container .

example:

```
mac local dir : users/vishnu/data/
```

which should get sync to

```
`<Docker-container-ID>:/opt/deploy/`
```

the container is already running ,i should not release the running container . i can only stop and start . is there a way ?? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

host mounted volume.

when you `docker run` you add a `-v /Users/vishnu/data:/opt/deploy` parameters.

if you need to add a mounted volume to your existing container, use the Kitematic UI. it's easier that way. but in general, you should add this when you `docker run`.

...

also, FYI - the idea that you can't delete a container is an anti-pattern with Docker. if you can't delete your container, because it would cause too many problems, you're doing something wrong. https://derickbailey.com/2017/04/05/what-i-learned-by-deleting-all-of-my-docker-images-and-containers/

Comment: i can't use docker volume because In Native docker we cant see the file system. what i need is to make the macs local directory to be synced with a directory in the docker container.

Comment: you either `COPY` the folder in the Dockerfile and build process, or you use a volume mount. by the way: i'm on a mac, and i use Docker for Mac all day, every day, with host mounted volumes. not sure where you read that it doesn't work.